# CORS support for PUT and DELETE with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am working with the final version of ASP.NET Web API to implement a JavaScript-friendly API. Per various tutorials, I have enabled CORS in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

With the above, cross-domain GET and POST requests work fine, but PUT and DELETE requests both fail.

In Chrome:

> Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
>
> Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Is there something additional required to get PUT and DELETE verbs working cross-domain?

Comment: How did you enabled CORS in your webconfig ?

Comment: Do you have a global CORS handler aswell? Or did you fix the CORS in the web.config only?

Comment: I implemented this at the web.config level only.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It looks like adding another custom header sorted it out:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only works for GET and POST.

Answer (score 34):

Also, in addition to Nathan answer, make sure you disabled WebDAV IIS module and set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` setting in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Without this, [preflight CORS requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) (which are used for PUT, DELETE methods and send additional OPTIONS request) will not work.

Comment: Ah thanks! My CORS handler wasn't working without those lines of code in web.config.

Comment: What is the `WebDAV` handler doing, and why does it need to be removed?

Comment: @JimAho: nice explaination is here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: OMG!!! I have expend almost 7 days for this!! and luckily i got it. Similar problem was for me. problem was for only PUT + DELETE . Finally Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Very simple solution to overcome CORS Issue in WEBAPI2.2.

Add the following in you WebApi Config File.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
Config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Before adding this make sure you remove the custom header in the Web.config file.

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
```

If you have both customheader as well the CORS enabled in WebApiconfig, you will face the cors error.

Add the cors enabled in WebApi config will solve the issue.

Comment: This is a good current solution and a good explanation. As you mentioned make sure both configurations don't exist (WebApiConfig.cs _and_ Web.config) or the CORS configuration will have a conflict and result in a `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:1234, *', but only one is allowed.` error.

Comment: In addition, one needs the following NuGet package to use the `EnableCorsAttribute` class: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this in web.config while you deployed your application,dont use in local web.config**

```
    <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 <ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the line: `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` in `<handlers>` tag