# Enabling CORS with WebAPI PUT / POST requests?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've tried following this post but I'm still not quite there:

[CORS support for PUT and DELETE with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api)

In my web.config I have the following:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!-- TODO: don't let anyone make requests - only approved clients -->
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

But in chrome when I make a POST request I get the Not Allowed error:

[image]

My request looks like this:

```js
var request = $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: apiEndpoint + 'api/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json'
        })
```

apiEndpoint is on localhost but on a different port - the client and api projects are in different solutions.

The POST request eventually makes its way to the server, but I always get an error related to OPTIONS and I never get a cookie saved to the client because of it.

I spent the last couple hours trying to get CORS with WebAPI working:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

But some assembly versioning issues led to me yanking everything out - hopefully there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

POST, PUT, DELETE, etc use pre-flighted CORS. The browser sends an OPTIONS request. Since you do not have an action method that handles OPTIONS, you are getting a 405. In its most simplest form, you must implement an action method like this in your controller.

```c#
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}
```

One thing to note is that the customHeaders you have configured in web.config will already be adding the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers. So the action method is not doing the same.

Implementing action method in controller works but may not be a good option. A better option will be to implement a message handler that does this for you. A much better option will be to use thinktecture identity model to enable CORS. [Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) has CORS support built-in (taken from ttidm).

Comment: Thank you Badri.  This has pushed me one step further!

Comment: How would you implement this in the controller?

Comment: Imo POST doesn't create preflight request

Comment: Last I heard, POST is pre-flighted, if content type is other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain. As per the code shown by OP, content type is application/json and that will be pre-flighted.

Comment: This Works like a charm!