# PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS for ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

Feel i've spent quite a lot of time trying to get this to work. There's a bunch of helpful SO answers on the topic:

- [How to support HTTP OPTIONS verb in ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application)
- [Enabling CORS with WebAPI PUT / POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498691/enabling-cors-with-webapi-put-post-requests?lq=1)
- [CORS support for PUT and DELETE with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api)

But... none actually solved mine. I feel it's time to phrase my own question, explain what i've done and what I experience is the issue I have.

1. Installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` via NuGet
2. Added attribute `[EnableCors("http://localhost:PORT", "*", "GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")]` on my WebAPI controller.

GET requests works at this point, like a charm.

When I do PUT or DELETE, the [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) fails. I get an internal server error reponse in the client browser. Turns out that the OPTIONS request fails because I have no options method in my web api controller.

By adding the options method as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
    return response;
}
```

PUT and DELETE requests does work, hurray!

I'm not sure where to draw the line of the responsibility of the developer vs the framework, but it *feels* like I should not have to care much about the OPTIONS method. **Must I really explicitly specify this method in order for PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS to work?**

Thanks for all help!

Comment: This solution worked for me I was facing a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233836/cors-issue-on-put/42234966#42234966