# Very Simple AngularJS $http POST Results in '400 (Bad Request)' and 'Invalid HTTP status code 400'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure

I have a very simple .NET Web API hosted in Azure, with two very simple methods:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://simpleapiearl.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class EnvelopesController : ApiController {
    // GET: api/Envelopes
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // POST: api/Envelopes
    public string Post([FromBody]Envelope env) {
        return "rval: " + env + " (and my addition to env)";
    }
}
```

I have created a [simple plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hY2OUeg9CRQ1QOz8MGU8) to call these methods.  In my AngularJS code, I'm making two very simple $http calls.  The GET works fine.  The POST, however, always returns a "400 (Bad Request)", followed shortly in my WebStorm console by "XMLHttpRequestion cannot load ... Invalid HTTP status code 400".

Any and all suggestions appreciated!

EDIT!!

Hello, and thanks for the very fast responses.  I just realized I forgot to add some very relevant detail.

The parameter to my POST method is what I call an Envelope object, which contains two properties: `listingId (int)`, and `Description (string)`.  When I add the urlencoded Content-Type header, and pass `'{"listingId":1234, "Description":"some description"}'` as my POST data, the env parameter in my POST method on the server is NULL (that is, it seems unable to parse the JSON I'm providing).  Sorry this was omitted from original post.

Comment: check whether u have any `xsrf` tokens in forms. if that is the case dont forget to send that token.

Comment: Preflight (OPTIONS) request is failing. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713412/cors-post-requests-not-working-options-bad-request-the-origin-is-not-allow

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this post would be helpful.

[How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs/24964658#24964658)

> By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by
>   serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content-
>   type, "application/json". When we want to post the value as a FORM
>   post, we need to change the serialization algorithm and post the data
>   with the content-type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

This is the modified plnkr from yours. Your code is missing conversion of JSON to encoded url.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4aeEDz73qgHSfOv1sBgn?p=preview

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://simpleApiEarl.azurewebsites.net/api/envelopes',
    data: env,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
      var str = [];
      for(var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
    }
  }).
```

Comment: Thanks for the very similar reply to what I ended up finding a short time ago.  Props!

Comment: np, configuring `$httpProvider.defaults` is a good idea if target host does not change.

Comment: @allenhwkim I have used the same code in my project the error still remains and in the description it says " Invalid Json " .Please guide me to resolve the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog post that corrected my issue:

http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Thanks to everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS you can do in an easier way.

You can inject `$httpParamSerializer` and then prepare your data through `$httpParamSerializer(data)`.

So your call should look something like:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://simpleApiEarl.azurewebsites.net/api/envelopes',
    data: $httpParamSerializer(env),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
```