# .NET Web API + AngularJS: CORS OPTIONS Request fails with 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

There have been many questions regarding this topic. I tried following their answers/solutions, but I seem to be missing something here.

I have the backend as .NET Web Api, with the following in its web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="authorization,content-type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,access-control-allow-origin"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

In frontend, I am making a POST request with JSON body content, like this:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: options.url,
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicAuth },
   data: dataObj
});
```

In Fiddler, the OPTIONS request looks like this:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:44302/my/url HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44302
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MyServices"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?blah blah
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,access-control-allow-origin
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 19:48:46 GMT
Content-Length: 2192

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>Request Error</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content">
          <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
          <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the blah blah,and a useless call stack</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The server response includes the allow-origin: *. It also includes the allow-methods and allow-headers requested in the OPTIONS request. Is there another requirement for the server to respond positively to the OPTIONS request? What else am I missing?

Comment: allow origin * isn't enough to tell your server it should respond to OPTIONS requests.

Comment: asp.net-web-api tag that I edited on is correct, yes?

Comment: I would disable authentication while troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: The custom headers are all evil as your app should only include them in response to preflight OPTIONS requests, though they are not the cause of 400.

Comment: check this qa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141359/very-simple-angularjs-http-post-results-in-400-bad-request-and-invalid-htt