# angularjs post 400 (bad request)

Tags: angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

i am trying to combine a cordova application with angularjs and ionic framework with a rest service for user login and register.

this is the code of data.js which connects to the rest api

```
app.factory("Data", ['$http', 'toaster',
function ($http, toaster) { // This service connects to our REST API

    var serviceBase = 'http://blace.co/task_manager/v1/';
    var obj = {};
    obj.toast = function (data) {
        toaster.pop(data.status, "", data.message, 10000, 'trustedHtml');
    }
    obj.get = function (q) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
        });
    };
    obj.post = function (q, object) {
         console.log(object);
    return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
    return results.data;
    });
    };
    obj.put = function (q, object) {
        return $http.put(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
        });
    };
    obj.delete = function (q) {
        return $http.delete(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
        });
    };

    return obj;
}]);
```

and this is the code of my controller   authCtrl.js

```
app.controller('authCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) {
//initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
$scope.login = {};
$scope.register = {};
$scope.doLogin = function (login) {
    Data.post('login').then(function (results) {
        Data.toast(results);
        if (results.status == "success") {
            $location.path('dashboard');
        }
    });
};
$scope.register = {};
$scope.Register = function (register) {
        Data.post('register').then(function (results) {
        Data.toast(results);
        if (results.status == "success") {
            $location.path('dashboard');
        }
    });
};
$scope.logout = function () {
    Data.get('logout').then(function (results) {
        Data.toast(results);
        $location.path('login');
    });
}
});
```

this one is the part of my rest api for the registar part

```
$app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'email', 'password'));

        $response = array();

        // reading post params
        $name = $app->request->post('name');
        $email = $app->request->post('email');
        $password = $app->request->post('password');

        // validating email address
        validateEmail($email);

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $res = $db->createUser($name, $email, $password);

        if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
        } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        } else if ($res == USER_ALREADY_EXISTED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Sorry, this email already existed";
        }
        // echo json response
        echoRespnse(201, $response);
    });
```

the rest api is working perfectly and i have checked it with Advanced Rest Client

you can see it here
[image](https://imgur.com/ICQlufa)

in internet explorer i have this error
BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax. (XHR): POST

i think the problem is that

By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content- type, "application/json". When we want to post the value as a FORM post, we need to change the serialization algorithm and post the data with the content-type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

[another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141359/very-simple-angularjs-http-post-results-in-400-bad-request-and-invalid-htt)

but i do not know how to implement this

any idea is appreciated!
thank you