# Upload file with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I am having trouble uploading a file with nodeJS and Angular.

I found solutions but it's only with Ajax which I don't know about. Is it possible to do without?

With the following code I get this error :

```
POST http://localhost:2000/database/sounds 413 (Payload Too Large)
```

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="upload-input">This needs to be a .WAV file</label>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/database/sounds" method="post">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploads[]" id="upload-input" multiple="multiple">
        </form>
        <button class="btn-primary" ng-click="uploadSound()">UPLOAD</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.uploadSound = function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("upload-input");
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            console.log("Select one or more files.");
        } else {
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                var file = x.files[i];
                if(file.type==("audio/wav")){
                    console.log("Importing :");
                    if ('name' in file) {
                        console.log("-name: " + file.name);
                    }
                    if ('size' in file) {
                        console.log("-size: " + file.size + " bytes");
                    }
                    formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
                }else{
                    console.log("Error with: '"+file.name+"': the type '"+file.type+"' is not supported.");
                }  
            }
            $http.post('/database/sounds', formData).then(function(response){
                console.log("Upload :");
                console.log(response.data);
            });

        }
    } 
}
```

NodeJS:

```
//Upload a sound
app.post('/database/sounds', function(req, res){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
  form.multiples = true;

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/database/sounds');

  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  form.parse(req);
});
```

EDIT:

The error became

```
POST http://localhost:2000/database/sounds 400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your are using bodyParser

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb',extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
```

This will allow you to upload files upto 100mb

Comment: I did that and now the error became

    `POST http://localhost:2000/database/sounds 400 (Bad Request)`

What is the problem ?

Comment: what is the size of file? check your browser network calls?

Comment: the file weights 160556 bytes and I get an unexpected token 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
    at parse (/home/chococo/API/test/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)`

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" should be in form tag right?

Comment: i forgot to put a form tag, I was doing this in the input tag. I edited the code in my question. I still have the same problem though even with the right form tag

Comment: I am doing my uploadSound() function with the button, maybe it is the problem ?

Comment: i think change this line formData.append('uploads['+i+']', file, file.name);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145560/discussion-between-dinesh-and-chococo35).

Answer (score 1):

For json/urlencoded limit, it’s recommended to configure them in server/config.json as follows:

```
{
“remoting”: {
“json”: {“limit”: “50mb”},
“urlencoded”: {“limit”: “50mb”, “extended”: true}
}
```

Please note loopback REST api has its own express router with bodyParser.json/urlencoded middleware. When you add a global middleware, it has to come before the boot() call.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

//request limit 1gb
app.use(loopback.bodyParser.json({limit: 524288000}));
app.use(loopback.bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: 524288000, extended: true}));
```

Comment: What is loopback used for? Can I keep using express if I don't need to have big files imported?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to checking that the data is actually a WAV file, your best bet is to look at the contents of the file and determine if it *looks like* a WAV file or not.

The [WAVE PCM soundfile format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) article goes into the details of the format.

To be absolutely sure that this is a proper WAV file, and it's not broken in some way, you need to check that all of the fields defined there make sense. But a quick solution, might be to just check that the first four bytes of the content are the letters 'RIFF'. It won't guard against corrupted files or malicious content, but it's a good place to start I think.

Comment: hey, thanks, I used : `if(file.type==("audio/wav"))` to check the data and it works fine. But I still have a problem passing the formData object

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the object sent to url params as said in [Very Simple AngularJS $http POST Results in '400 (Bad Request)' and 'Invalid HTTP status code 400'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141359/very-simple-angularjs-http-post-results-in-400-bad-request-and-invalid-htt) :

```
$http.post({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/upload',
                data: formData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                }
            }).success(function(response){
                console.log("Uploaded :");
                console.log(response.data);
            });
```

But I get a bad request error

Why is there no data received ? The console.log before this shows I have one file in my formData.

Error: $http:badreq
Bad Request Configuration

```
Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted 
object.  Received: {"method":"POST","url":"/upload","data":
{},"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}
```