# Angular.js $resource with ASP.Net webapi?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple ASP.Net WebAPI service that assigns a static variable on POST/PUT and returns the value on GET:

```
private static State Repo = null;

public State Get()
{
    return Repo;
}

public void Post(State value)
{
    Repo = value;
}

public void Put(State value)
{
    Repo = value;
}
```

And I have an angular-resource defined like so:

```
var stateService = angular.module('StateService', ['ngResource']);

stateService.factory('State', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/API/State');
});
```

When I try to do this:

```
State.get(function (state) {
    $scope.data = state.data !== undefined ? state.data : '[Not Set]';

    state.data = "newvalue";
    state.$save();
});
```

The `get()` works fine, but the `$save()` throws this error in chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/API/State. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

The webAPI already has CORS enabled (returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some CORS requests, the browser sends an additional request, called a “preflight request”, before it sends the actual request for the resource.

The pre-flight request uses the HTTP OPTIONS (405 status code) method. It includes two special headers:

- Access-Control-Request-Method: The HTTP method that will be used for
  the actual request.
- Access-Control-Request-Headers: A list of request
  headers that the application set on the actual request. (Again, this
  does not include headers that the browser sets.)

Even if you had made it CORS enabled, and it is working for `GET` request and you have told it is showing `405 HTTP Status` for `POST` request. This is because, `POST,PUT,DELETE` request are not safe request, they first send request `OPTIONS` request, you have to respond to that will required hedaers such as  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` , `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST`, and then it will again send `POST` request , and it will work then.

Please verify what are the headers you are sending in response. i.e. To make successful `CORS POST` request, atleast you have to send `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST` along with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Steps to make it CORS enabled:

1. Install this - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors using NuGet
2. Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method.
3. Next, add the [EnableCors] attribute to the Controller class:

   With following params

   [EnableCors(origins: "your_domain", headers: "*", methods: "POST")]
4. Redeploy your WebAPI project.

SOURCE - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

More links - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En

Comment: For CORS request, PUT , POST, DELETE does not works , straight forward, it will 1st send you 405 `OPTIONS` request, then you have to respond to that will the above header, after that it will work. I have already answered this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889599/wcf-rest-service-template-40cs-cross-domain-error, But this is for WCF, i am looking for `WebAPI`, will post that shortly.Are you also sending this `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST` header?

Comment: Is there a way to do this from IIS? I tried adding them to IIS but they have no effect. However, they work like a charm when I add them to the webAPI code.

Comment: You need to set some of attributes to post methods, such as `methods`, `headers` , then it should work.

Comment: @ArindamNayak, If CORS is enabled by `EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");`, then is it mandatory to do specify "POST" explictly?? Also, i tried to enable it in web.config, that doesnt work.. any explanations for it?

Comment: @TechQuery, some browser don't like `origins = *`, may be for a security risk, you need to specify exact domain. Regarding methods, post, put, delete as unsafe method, so that go through CORS.

Comment: @ArindamNayak thanks Arindam. And why doesnt work when i use it in web.config..? Is it not the preferred way of doing it in webAPI? And also my Test application works fine wiht CORS nuget package but not my real one where the access-control allow origin is not getting added at all:(

Answer (score 0):

On Web.config, comment the line `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` at

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
```

If you are using CORS config by web.config file.