# ASP.NET WebApi Answer 400 Bad Request to OPTIONS on ValidateClientAuthentication, even on context.Validated()

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, typescript, cors, preflight

I have an angularjs HTML client to a WebApi project. When I test the APIs via POSTMAN or other REST Client, it seems that everything is ok.

When I start using browsers with my angularjs client, browsers always start preflight requests with OPTIONS. There, my WebAPI always answers 400 Bad Request - I am still on a "/api/token" phase.

I have already attached every single point of my WebAPI project to the debugger. I have also changed several points according to several answers here in SO on how to enable CORS. Some of them I have already tried: changing web.config to add headers enabling cors on every request, adding cors to WebApi startup, enabling cors at "/token" overridden functions.

Here is what I got so for:

Angularjs TypeScript call to "/api/token":

```
logIn = (userName: string, userPassword: string): ng.IPromise<void> => {
    var postData = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": this.appConfiguration.ClientId,
        "client_secret": this.appConfiguration.ClientSecret,
        "username": userName,
        "password": userPassword
    };
    return this.$http.post<models.LoggedUserModel>('http://local.web.api/api/token', $.param(postData), {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        this.localStorageService.set('Auth', result);
        this.goHome(true);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
    });
}
```

Here is the only function that is called on my WebApi:

```
  public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
  {
      // handle cors requests
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.OwinContext.Request.Headers.Get("Origin")))
      {
          context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new string[] { "*" });
      }
      try
      {
          // retrieve clientId and clientSecret from request body
          string clientId;
          string clientSecret;
          if (context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
          {
              // here it comes our application specific security code....
          }
          else
          {
              // this is part of enabling CORS..
              if (context.Request.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
              {
                  // it returns OK to preflight requests having an empty body
                  context.Validated();
              }
          }
      }
      finally
      {
          // log stuff...
      }
  }
```

If I just left OWIN Cors stuff, adding headers and calling ´context.Validated()´ it all continues the same. Here is what I get:

```
Firefox Network Tab:
--------------------
Request URL: http://local.web.api/api/token
Request method: OPTIONS
Remote address: 127.0.0.1:80
Status code: 400 Bad Request
Version: HTTP/1.1

Request headers:
----------------
Host: local.web.api
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,pt-BR;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://local.web.client
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Response headers:
-----------------
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 34
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 15:24:23 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I would really appreciate some ideas of where to got.
This is brand new to me, and I do operate some other WebApi projects + angularjs.

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST`, OPTIONS is not allowed and returns error, you need to include `OPTIONS` in configuration and `OPTIONS` call must return `200 OK` content is not necessary.

IMHO best source for CORS info
http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I followed all adivces on http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html to enable CORS, but I am still receiving 400 Bad Request. Where should I add `OPTIONS`? What configuration? Since I the only point my WebApi project reaches is `ValidateClientAuthentication`, should I return another thing than just calling `context.Validated()`? Thanks for the link!

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713412/cors-post-requests-not-working-options-bad-request-the-origin-is-not-allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's is terrible but I found the issue.
I am using a http interceptor on angularjs that would automatically check for a logged user and add an `Authorization` header with the `Bearer` token when needed. Problem is I was doing it wrongly.

I created a new property in the `config` object, `bypassToken` as boolean, that would be the flag to add or not the `Authorization` header. Removing this actually fixed the code. Not sure why, but analyzing the request now I can see that all headers are actually sending as expected: with the `Content-Type` which was not being filled on the first case correctly. Weird though no warning was thrown by angularjs.

```
// http auth interceptor
angularApplication.factory('httpAuthInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$injector', '$location', ($rootScope, $injector, $location): ng.IHttpInterceptor => {

    var $q: ng.IQService = $injector.get('$q');
    var localStorageService: ng.local.storage.ILocalStorageService = $injector.get('localStorageService');

    return {
        request: (config: ng.IRequestConfig): ng.IRequestConfig => {
            // check if headers are present
            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            // the error was here! I was trying to add properties to config that I think angular was not expecting
            // removing this line solved the issue
            // if (!config.bypassToken) {

            // check if user is logged in
            var loggedUserInfo = localStorageService.get<models.LoggedUserInfoModel>('Auth');
            if (loggedUserInfo) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + loggedUserInfo.access_token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: (rejection)  => {
            // check if user is logged in
            var loggedUserInfo = localStorageService.get<models.LoggedUserInfoModel>('Auth');
            if ((rejection.status === 401) && (loggedUserInfo)) {

                // if so, then the user must login againd
                localStorageService.remove('Auth');
                $location.path('/home');
                console.error(rejection);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I appreciate your help.
I am only posting this here in case someone faces a similar issue.
Don't mess with the `config` object!