# .NET Web API CORS PreFlight Request

Tags: .net, cors, http-delete, preflight

I have some trouble make PUT and DELETE CORS request to Web API on other domain.

I've coded API by tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#create-webapi-project.

GET and POST Requests works fine, but DELETE and PUT doesn't. I get this message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I add code to WebConfig suggested on [CORS support for PUT and DELETE with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api) , I get only first error.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add a handler to deal with this type of request.

Create a class derive from "DelegatingHandler":

```
public class PreflightRequestsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method.Equals("OPTIONS"))
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
            // Define and add values to variables: origins, headers, methods (can be global)               
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origins);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", methods);
            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(response);
            return tsc.Task;
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

}
```

Later in WebApiconfig.cs in Register method add this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Define and add values to variables: origins, headers, methods (can be global) 
    // Enable global CORS
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, headers, methods));

    // Add handler to deal with preflight requests, this is the important part
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PreflightRequestsHandler()); // Defined above
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: The interesting thing about this is that this handler does NOT get called on requests from Chrome. O_o

Comment: after adding '**response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");**' in response headers, it works fine for me

Answer (score 5):

The AJAX call you're doing to the Web API is triggering a Preflight check (HTTP verb "OPTIONS"). This needs to be handled by your system otherwise you'll get the 405 error. There are a few answers on how to do that here on SO, like:

[Handling CORS Preflight requests to ASP.NET MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions)

You can also avoid this preflight call altogether if you follow the following guidelines.

```
The browser can skip the preflight request if the following conditions are true:

The request method is GET, HEAD, or POST, **and**
The application does not set any request headers other than Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, or Last-Event-ID, **and**
The Content-Type header (if set) is one of the following:
 - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 - multipart/form-data
 - text/plain
```

Taken from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api (under "Preflight Requests"):

Answer (score 2):

In my case CORS wasn't working for XHR requests with custom header (because it requires preflight OPTIONS request). I configured CORS as described in [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Solution was to add this to `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Without this configuration the IIS will intercept OPTION requests and after adding this config ASP.NET can handle it.

I found the solution on [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a preflight issue(404 error) on GET request with firefox & chrome browsers which actually converted to OPTIONS request,after spending hours I found that if we remove the Content-type parameter from AJAX call we can get the data from server.