# Calling PUT method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, put

I'm trying to call my C# Web API from javascript, and the data doesn't appear to be passing correctly.  The GET method I have works perfectly fine, but I can't seem to get the PUT working as I intend.  Here's the structure:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/FTP",
    data: "Hello World"
})
```

C# Web API:

```
public class FTPController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/FTP
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/FTP
    public void Put([FromBody] string data)
    {
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more info.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are both the client and server applications on the same domain?  I had trouble with that myself once, but never had the opportunity to set it straight.  Here's a good resource on it, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792950/net-web-api-cors-preflight-request

Comment: Yep, both just going off of my local machine.  Like I said, the GET is working fine.

Comment: HTTP ERROR 405 is "Method not allowed", so probably IIS or the app must be configured to accept PUT. It may be a configuration error, nothing seems wrong in your code.

Comment: @pid so how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: You can change IIS settings to allow that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739124/iis-7-5-enable-put-and-delete-for-restful-service-extensionless

Comment: I tried removing the argument (string data) from the api and it hits it just fine.  It has something to do with how I'm passing that argument.

Comment: Maybe try adding: contentType: "text/plain" to your ajax request, as it defaults to: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

Comment: Change your `PUT` to a `POST`.

Comment: @RickS albeit this would probably work, I sense here an intent to have a RESTful API, so all those HTTP methods should be in working order.

Comment: @Nealon As @ajiliptak suggested, if you set type to JSON you probably should pass valid JSON. Try replacing the text with `{"message":"Hello, World!"}` or switching to the `text/plain` type.

Comment: My goal is to pass plain text to the PUT.  I tried adding a `[FromBody]` to the Web API, and now it's hitting the API, but `data` is `null`

Comment: I updated my post to reflect my current attempts...

Comment: @nealon dataType is what is expect back from the server, contentType is what you are sending.

Comment: does 'type' need changed to 'method'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try data:{'':'Hello World'}

it will generate =HelloWorld as form data and this is what [FromBody] expects and it's in this case I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT", //HTTP VERB
    url: "/api/FTP", //URL
    dataType: 'json', //What type of response you expect back from the server
    contentType: 'text/plain', //What type of data you are trying to send
    data: "Hello World"

})
```

Comment: setting contentType actually results in a 415 error for me.

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.