# Cross-domain jQuery AJAX fails when defining Content-Type

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI client which has the following configuration which allows any cross-domain `POST` and `GET` calls:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST"));

    // other unrelated configurations
}
```

I have AJAX calls to my WebAPI application and all of them are failing with a CORS prevention message in a console.

The following AJAX request fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myserver:8081/User/Get",
    data: {
        "Id": 12
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; encoding=utf-8"
});
```

Why does this happen and how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have spent a bunch of time "fighting" with WebAPI CORS when suddenly I have understood that the problem is in AJAX call. This request executes successfully:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myserver:8081/User/Get",
    data: {
        "Id": 12
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    // contentType: "application/json; encoding=utf-8"
});
```

According to **[`jQuery.ajax() documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**,

> For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

Browser is preflighting the request to look for CORS headers and discover if server allows cross-domain requests and making a real request is safe. If the request is acceptable, it will then send the real request.

A browser sends a preflight request is:

- HTTP method is not `GET`, `POST` or `HEAD`;
- or if `Content-Type` is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`;
- or if any custom HTTP headers are set.

So, Chrome sends `OPTIONS` "preflight" request. Insofar as I allow only `POST` and `GET` requests at the server, the browser thinks that it is a CORS violation and denies request.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete) is directly related to this question and explains what is "preflight" request and why does a browser need to send it.

The solution was as simple as the problem cause - don't specify Content-Type in cross-domain AJAX calls.

If you need to specify custom headers or `Content-Type` for your requests, you can implement a specal handler which will allow preflight requests. [This StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792950/net-web-api-cors-preflight-request) describes how to do this.

I hope that it will help someone to save time.