# 404 error when calling API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm using the microsoft asp.net identity tutorial sample app [Here][1] just until I feel comfortable with the functionality needed for my project. I need to have an API that I can call from a separate MVC web app to do authentication/authorization against a local sql server and pass login credentials from the web app to the api to get the header token etc. Then I need to be able to check the token for any requests to pull data or save data back to the db.

I added a web app project to that example solution that is just a form with a button and some jquery to catch the submit button being clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var register = function() {
        var dataa = {
            Email: "password@host.com",
            Password: "password",
            ConfirmPassword: "password"
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Account/Register',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataa)
        });
        return false;
    }

    $('#btnRegister').click(register);
});
```

and then here is the controller on the api itself:

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors("*","*","*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When I try to call the Register function on the api I get a 404 error (jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 POST http://localhost:35714/api/Account/Register 404 (Not Found)) in browser. How can I hit the api function from the front end, and can this call be made from my web app Controller or should it be client side?

Added Microsoft.aspnet.cors and microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors, added config.EnableCors() to webapiconfig.cs and [EnableCors] to the accountcontroller that inherits from apicontroller.

Comment: Replace `'api/Account/Register'` with `'/api/Account/Register'` (prepend a `/` to the url to make it absolute)

Comment: I noticed that as well and updated my code to reflect that I already tried that, same error.

Comment: Did you make sure your your Url is indeed `/api/Account/Register`?

Comment: Also, try to decorate your `Register` method with `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]`

Comment: Added the HttpPost Data Annotation and now I'm getting a different error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44305/api/Account/Register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:35714' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: You need to enable CORS then: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Enabled CORS, error changed once again:

>XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44305/api/Account/Register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'http://localhost:35714' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: That's the same error. Update your question with how you enabled CORS.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect that I added CORS. Does both projects being on the same solution as I'm testing locally impact this issue because they would be separate when deployed?

Comment: Just adding the NuGet packages is not enough. Read through the page I linked earlier. At the most basic level, you'll have to call `EnableCors()` on your `HttpConfiguration` (in your `Startup.cs)`

Comment: I apologize, I didn't notate that but it was in my code. In WebApiConfig I added config.EnableCors() to the register method, and in my AccountController that inherits from ApiController I added the [EnableCors] annotation. Still getting the 500 error I posted when I run.

Comment: If preflight options checks are still your problem create a custom message handler. See the answer by MCurbelo [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792950/net-web-api-cors-preflight-request). Worked for me in my Web API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add HttpPost attribute to your API method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    ...
```

Comment: I've done that, and also implemented CORS but now I'm getting an error code 500

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var register = function() {
        var dataa = {
            Email: "password@host.com",
            Password: "password",
            ConfirmPassword: "password"
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Account/Register',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {model: JSON.stringify(dataa)}
        });
        return false;
    }

    $('#btnRegister').click(register);
});
```