# ASP.NET Web API & REACT - CORS Issue in ASP.NET Identity Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, webpack

Hello I'm having an Issue with ASP.NET WEB API Login. I've already enabled CORS in my back end

here is from my WebApiConfig.cs

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

web.config

```
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
```

from my REACT APP

```
 var params = {
                'userName' : this.state.email,
                'password' : this.state.password,
                'grant_type' : 'password'
            };

            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var k in params) {
                formData.append(k, params[k]);
            }

            fetch(loginApiUrl, {
                method: 'post',
                headers : {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body : formData
            })
            .then(json => json())
            .then(x => {
                alert(json.access_token)
               // localStorage.setItem('auth_token', `Bearer ${json.access_token}`)
            })
```

And I also use webpack dev server here is the config to allow CORS

```
 devServer : {
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
        contentBase : path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress : true,
        hot: true,
        open: true,
    },
```

And I keep getting this error from Google chrome console

> Failed to load http://localhost:xxxx/token: Response for preflight
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

Any help to get this to use OPTIONS verb?

Comment: create a handler for Options request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792950/net-web-api-cors-preflight-request

Comment: Didn't work for me 

Comment: Somehow my temporary solution is to use a View from my ASP.NET MVC App