# xmlhttprequest cannot load response URL. for preflight has invalid http status code 405 for $http.delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have web API service:

```
public void Delete(int id)
        {
}
```

Web api-Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

when I use it using Postman (Chrome extension). I am passing data as 'form data'. And I get 200 return code.
I have call this method using angularjs:

```
deletesurvey: function(surveyData) {
                var objFormData = new FormData();
                for (var key in surveyData)
                    objFormData.append(key, surveyData[key]);
                return $http.delete(configurationurl + 'Survey', objFormData, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                });
```

i have set headers in my Web.Config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Request-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />

      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

after it call deletesurvey function it is giving me error (Browser is Chrome)
**xmlhttprequest cannot load response URL for preflight has invalid http status code 405**

Comment: The error message is about the preflight OPTIONS request, not the DELETE request which the browser never makes (because it doesn't get permission in the response to the OPTIONS request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) 'preflight' request (which uses the `OPTIONS` method) is not/incorrectly handled by the server.

Suggested reading:

- [HTML5 Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)
- [The awesome Enable CORS website](http://enable-cors.org/)

The response to the `preflight` request should contain something like

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
```

(`Access-Control-Request-Method` being the main focus here)

---

As to why the 'Postman'-extension does not give this nag, it is simply not affected by the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: But how should i set in my application. so that it works

Comment: My knowledge on ASP.NET environment is limited (read: non-existent), I recon you should add the more relevant `asp.net` tag. The only thing I can do is provide a link to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api) (similar as far as I can determine)

Comment: i have added webapi web.config.